# What Java frameworks operate in a similar way to PHP?

Tags: java, php, web, webserver

I've been using PHP for quite a while, and it's been fine. A love-hate relationship as some would say. For my job however, I use Java on a daily basis.

Now I know many things exist to use Java for web servers, however I just can't seem to find a good place to start. While I know they're not the two closest languages, are there are web server frameworks for Java that work at least somewhat like PHP?

Comment: Not me, but I can guess: this is off-topic, either because it's Too Broad or it's a Recommendation Question. Have a read of the help section to see what sort of questions best fit here - it is unusually good!

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant for you: For small/private projects PHP hosting is available for very little cost. For java you need a root server which is much more expensive.

Comment: I quite understand, I have shared hosting and a few dozen dedis.

Comment: @BetaRide, agreed, although even virtual servers are pretty cheap these days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: [JSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages) is very similar to PHP. (From the linked Wikipedia pages on JavaServer Pages)

```
<p>Counting to three:</p>
<% for (int i=1; i<4; i++) { %>
  <p>This number is <%= i %>.</p>
<% } %>
<p>OK.</p>
```

Longer answer: There are many technologies in the [Web Profile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Enterprise_Edition#Web_Profile) for the Java Enterprise Edition.